# how can i define a object with Variables?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I want to add to Object with variables, like this

```
a = 'name'
object = {'age': 12, 'weight': 120}
```

I want this to

```
{'name': 'bob'}
```

I do this

```
object = {a: 'bob'}
```

but it give me

```
{'a': 'bob'}
```

how can I fixed it? I must use variables

Answer (score 2):

Just assign it with the bracket notation after deleting the former content.

```js
var a = 'name',
    object = { 'age': 12, 'weight': 120 };

object = {};       // delete all properties
object[a]= 'Bob';  // assign new property
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(object, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: this will give me `{'name': 'bob', 'age':  12, 'weight': 120}`  I just want  `{'age':  12, 'weight': 120}` to `{'name': 'bob'}`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in one line. But you can do like this :

```
object = {};
object [a] = 'bob';
```

Answer (score 0):

In ECMAScript 2015 there are [*computed property names*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object-initializer):

```
var a = 'name';
var obj = {[a]:'fred'};
```

However there may not be sufficient support yet. See the [*MDN browser compatability table*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Browser_compatibility).